# Getting Spring to work with Play Framework 2.1 (java)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to get Spring working in my Playframework 2.1 project but with no success yet.
I'm following [Guilliaume Bort's tutorial](https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo) on how to get it to work.
The project starts correctly, it calls the action (via GET) signupForm fine(described below) but when I try to submit the form, I get the next Exception:

[image: Exception gotten]

It seems to not like the @Transactional annotation.
This is part my controller code:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class UserController extends Controller {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public Result signupForm() {
        // This is the initial method called via GET (works fine)
    }

    @Transactional
    public Result signup() {
            ... code ....
            userService.save(user); // call to the injected service
            ... more code ...
        }
    }
    ... mode code ...
```

This is my components.xml (placed in /conf):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers, services, dataaccess, models"/>
</beans>
```

(dataaccess is where my dao's are placed)

This is part of my service (just in case it is necessary):

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    ... more code ...
```

And finally this is part of the relevant Dao for this case:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoJpa implements UserDao {
    ... more code ...
```

As you can see in the image below, the getControllerInstance method in Global is trying to get an instance of the Transactional annotation and I don't know why. To me, it shouldn't be trying to instantiate it. It isn't event in the auto scanned packages by spring.

[image: This is what spring tries to instantiate]

Thank you for any help you could provide.

PS: I'm new to spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably imported [`play.db.jpa.Transactional`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.x/java/play/db/jpa/Transactional.html) instead of [`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).

The first one wraps the annotated action in `TransactionalAction`, of which Spring has no idea and hence the lookup fails.

You probably also want to move transaction handling to your service layer.

Comment: I have a new problem, now I get an exception stating "Execution exception[[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]]". It seems to be because I remove the play.db.jpa.Transactional from my action and added spring Transactional in my service. What could I do?

Comment: @monkeydeveloper i don't see transaction manager configured in your context. Try adding `<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>` and it's dependencies in `components.xml`. Read more about it [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html)

Answer (score -2):

Just register the TransactionalAction class to your spring context

```
<bean class="play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction"/>
```